# How to create a non clustered index specified by tuning Advisor, EF6.1 Code First

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, indexing, ef-code-first

I've run a couple of examples through SQL Server Tuning Advisor and it has recommended an index, however I'm not quite sure how I would implement them with code first.

```
public class Exchange
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ExchangeSetId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(5)]
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string BasePrefix { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string BaseLabel { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string BaseLocation { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string DestPrefix { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string DestLabel { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string DestLocation { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Rule { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
}
```

The Index Tuning Advisor suggests is as follows

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_Exchanges_5_661577395__K3_K4_K7] ON [dbo].[Exchanges]
(
    [AreaCode] ASC,
    [BasePrefix] ASC,
    [DestPrefix] ASC
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How would I go about adding this to my DB Context / Model?

Any help tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why dont you run this command in sql server management studio for your db?

Comment: If i need to recreate the db for what ever reason, ill have to remember to add all the indexing again, i thought it might be appropriate to include it in the code first (maybe)

Comment: Have you validated whether that recommendation makes sense or not? Seems like an overly big index - basically including **all** columns from your table - that basically just **duplicates** your data. I would first think about whether this makes sense (or not) - and only if it does figure out how to do it.... in my opinion, this makes no sense at all...

Comment: Good point, i'm guessing it doesnt

Comment: My bad, garbage in, garbage out, edited with the correct index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using EF 6.1 you can use [IndexAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/data/jj591583.aspx#Index%5d). You add it to properties:

```
[Index("IndexName", 1)]
[Required]
[MaxLength(5)]
public string AreaCode { get; set; }    

[Index("IndexName", 2)]
[Required]
[MaxLength(10)]
public string BasePrefix { get; set; }

[Index("IndexName", 3)]
[Required]
[MaxLength(10)]
public string DestPrefix { get; set; }
```

If you are using migrations you will need to add it using `CreateIndex()` option.

Comment: Thanks for that, does that satisfy the asc?